# rating system in rails, is it possible with my set up?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Any help would be appreciated -- I just started rails a few weeks ago and I'm pretty lost right now. So I made an app where people can submit questions, and those questions get randomized and displayed one at a time. I implemented this in a pretty roundabout way. I'm going to lay out what I did explicitly just in case.

I created a Question Model as well as a Question controller with new and create actions -- I put a form to submit the question in the view associated with the new action. To display the questions, I used javascript. I first used embedded ruby within the page to iterate through all the questions in the database. I then put them all in their own `<li>` and set the class of that to have a display: none. Then I used javascript to grab the class of the `<li>` tag and pushed all the questions onto an array.

Then, I just used javascript to display the question one at a time by updating a div element's html over and over again. Now, I want to add a simple rating system (like an +1 or -1 thing). I want to take people's ratings of the question and average them out. But I don't really know how to implement this. I THINK that I should have a ratings model that belongs_to the question model (which has_many ratings). There should be a ratings controller with an edit and update action that changes the score every time someone rates a question.

The problem is I don't know how to exactly implement this given what I've already done so far. A big problem for me is having the rating of the question linked to the question itself when I just used javascript to display the questions. Any suggestions? Apologies for the essay.

Comment: Can you post you code? It's a lot easier for us to understand reading the code itself (models/views/controller/javascript)

Comment: Also, the rating model you suggested sounds sensible (to track votes after the fact), but it might be worth having a column like on the question model itself to keep the current rating (so it doesn't have to go through all the rating objects and calculate the total every time). Alternatively if you don't care about who rates what you could just have that column to be fair and no model. Do you even have users? Do you need to track individual ratings?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should clarify what you mean by using JS to display your questions. It sounds like what you're doing is more or less right, if indeed you need to dynamically update the page through time, but it also potentially sounds like you just want to show a list of questions, which you can do with just HTML.

Second, you should decide whether or not you really need an extra Ratings model. It could be useful so that you can track things like when ratings come in, who made which ratings, and how it changes over time; but if you really just want to know the rating at any given time, you can just have an integer `rating` column on your questions.

Third, displaying your ratings just involves grabbing more info from the questions when you display them. Assuming you have an `@question` object in the view, and you were displaying its text like `@question.text`, you can do the same with the rating by doing `@question.rating`, or, if you go the model route, something like `@question.ratings.count`. From there if you still want to use JS to update the value you need to either just make a string or convert the entire object into JSON so that you can handle it in JS.

Finally, you mention needing a Ratings controller. That's fine, but recognize that you're going to need AJAX on your page to send events to that controller so that you can tie clicks (for voting) to actual database changes.

Comment: I have the equivalent of @question.rating, but I can't figure out how to make a form that posts correctly to update the rating. Any ideas? For the url, it would have to be something like question_path(current_question), but that would 1. stay the same even if the current question changes unless I refresh the page and 2. I don't see a way to store the current question since I pick the current question with javascript, not rails.

Comment: It sounds like it would be helpful for you to go through the Rails guides again--specifically, the [forms](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html), [controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html), and [javascript](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html) guides. I can't really give you a tutorial from scratch, but it's basic Rails to create a controller that can process update events, and then basic JS to write AJAX that sends requests to that controller.

Comment: Specifically, it seems like you're wondering how to dynamically route to a controller--again, plucking your values with JS and then feeding them to AJAX is exactly what AJAX is for (no need to rely on question_path or form helpers--those are just Rails-ese to make life simpler, but you don't need to be bound by them).